# How to stream only the answer and not the whole process?

Tags: javascript, stream, chatbot, openai-api, langchain

I want to stream only the answer and not the whole process with the handleLLMNewToken callback,
The " console.log(response.output) " is the  text I want to stream through the handleLLMNewToken and i dont know how to filter the tokens.

```
const model = new ChatOpenAI({
        modelName:"gpt-3.5-turbo",
        temperature:0.5,
        streaming:true,
        callbacks:[
            {
                handleLLMNewToken(token){
                    res.write(token);
                }
            },
        ]
    });

//rest of the code
const executer = await initializeAgentExecutorWithOptions(
        [qaTool],
        model,
        {
        agentType: "zero-shot-react-description",
        agentArgs:{
            prefix,
        },
    }
    );
   
    console.log("Loaded the agent...");

    response = await executer.call({intput:prompt});
    console.log(response.output);

    res.end();
```

The problem with this code is that it stream the whole process such as: input action final action and I want a normal answer

Comment: Hello, ok why dont you add conditon if {response.output has includes (token)} then only res.write

Comment: resonse.output is built from tokens and I want to stream live so it's not that possible

Comment: is it possible to share github or gist so we could recreate

Comment: const chain = RetrievalQAChain.fromLLM(model,retriever,{
        agentType:"zero-shot-react-description",
        verbose:true,
        agentArgs:{
            prefix
        }
    });
    
    await chain.run(prompt);
This code works fine for me and it stream what i want.
but i dont know if the agetArgs is suitable for this method.
all i want is to direct the chain and be able to give it a describtion even though its not an agent...

Answer (score 0):

you need to use [FinalStreamingStdOutCallbackHandler](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/agents/how_to/streaming_stdout_final_only) callback handler. it is specifically built for this. From the link:

```
from langchain.callbacks.streaming_stdout_final_only import (FinalStreamingStdOutCallbackHandler)
```

this is `python` documentation. I could not find the same callback handler in
[langchain](https://www.npmjs.com/package/langchain). so you have to write your custom callback handler. [this is the documentation](https://js.langchain.com/docs/modules/callbacks/how_to/create_handlers) for javascript